# Powershell combine multiple string manipulations

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to get a folder name and all of its files below said folder into 1 string then do some string manipulation to remove all of the bits and pieces I dont want eg. File called RemoveMe, file extensions, _Config. All I want is the numbers, with the leading 0's present on from the folder and the leading 0's to be removed from the file

What I have got so far is working and is doing what I want it to but it is very very messy and was wondering if at the very least there is a way to maybe combine and tidy up some of the string manipulations I am doing?

File Structure like this

```
C:\SomeFile\
|Folder001
    | File001_Config
    | File002_Config
    | File003_Config
    | RemoveMe
|Folder002
    | File004_Config
    | File005_Config
    | File006_Config
    | RemoveMe
|Folder003
    | File010_Config
    | File020_Config
    | File030_Config
    | RemoveMe
```

Current Code

```
$Files = "C:\SomeFile\"

$Directories = @( (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory $Files).Name)


foreach($Directories in $Directories){
    $Item = @( (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $Files$Directories).Name)
    $CSVInfo = $Directories + "," + $Item
    $CSVInfo = $CSVInfo.Replace(".txt","")
    $CSVInfo = $CSVInfo.Replace("RemoveMe","")
    $CSVInfo = $CSVInfo.Replace("Folder","")
    $CSVInfo = $CSVInfo.Replace("File","")
    $CSVInfo = $CSVInfo.Replace("_Config","")
    $CSVInfo = $CSVInfo.Replace(" 0"," ")
    $CSVInfo = $CSVInfo.Replace(" 0","")

    $CSVInfo | Out-File C:\SomeFile\Output.csv -Append

}
```

I know this probabily isnt the best way to do it by getting all of this into 1 string for each folder then exporting that to a CSV and appending for each of the following folders but its working and it is only a quick tempory solution.

Comment: I think better check for regex operation and where-object.

Comment: You can actually remove everything except of the numbers different to zero with one `-replace` like this `-replace '^.*?([1-9]+).*?$', '$1'`

Comment: [1] please show what you want from each of the samples you list. [2] your `foreach` _should not work_ - even tho you say it works - since you are using the same name for the collection AND the current item.

Comment: [3] also, naming the source dir variable `$Files` is ... remarkably confusing. i would change it to match what it is - the `$SourceDir`. [*grin*]